# Accessing the data from MPI_Irecv()

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I was wondering why I cannot access the data from the MPI_Recv command. I have an array of 100 elements which I would like to group into 8 processes. Since 100/8 returns unequal lengths of chunks, I do this manually. I calculate then chunks and submit those to each process individually. Each process then performs an action on a chunk of the array, let's say reshuffles it, and then returns its reshuffled part which I then combine into an original array. The program runs well until a point where I have to group the outcomes from the slave processes together. In particular I would like to access the arrays which have just been returned by slave processes

```
for (i=1; i<numProcs; i++) {
MPI_Irecv (&msgsA[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);
MPI_Irecv (&msgsB[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);
MPI_Irecv (chunk, n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);

// how to access chunk, take part from msgsA[i] to msgsB[i] and assign to a part of a different array??

}
```

The whole code

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXPROCS 8 /* max number of processes */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, j, n=100, numProcs, myid, tag=55, msgsA[MAXPROCS], msgsB[MAXPROCS], myStart, myEnd;
double *chunk = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
double *K1 = malloc (n*sizeof(double));

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

if(myid==0) {
/* split the array into pieces and send the starting and finishing indices to the slave processes */
for (i=1; i<numProcs; i++) {
    myStart = (n / numProcs) * i + ((n % numProcs) < i ? (n % numProcs) : i);
    myEnd = myStart + (n / numProcs) + ((n % numProcs) > i) - 1;
    if(myEnd>n) myEnd=n;
    MPI_Isend(&myStart, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req[i]);
    MPI_Isend(&myEnd, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req[i]);
}
/* starting and finish values for the master process */
myStart = (n / numProcs) * myid + ((n % numProcs) < myid ? (n % numProcs) : myid);
myEnd = myStart + (n / numProcs) + ((n % numProcs) > myid) - 1;

for (i=1; i<numProcs; i++) {
  MPI_Irecv (&msgsA[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);
  MPI_Irecv (&msgsB[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);
  MPI_Irecv (chunk, n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);

// --- access the chunk array here, take part from msgsA[i] to msgsB[i] and assign to a part of a different array

}
//calculate a function on fragments of K1 and returns void

/* Wait until all chunks have been collected */
MPI_Waitall(numProcs-1, &recv_req[1], &status[1]);
}

else {  
    //calculate a function on fragments of K1 and returns void

    MPI_Isend (K1, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, tag+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_req[0]);
    MPI_Wait(&send_req[0], &status[0]);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. What was causing the problems was MPI_Irecv(). With non-blocking receiver I couldn't access the chunk variable. So the solution seems to be just

```
MPI_Status status[MAXPROCS];

for (i=1; i<numProcs; i++) {
MPI_Irecv (&msgsA[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);
MPI_Irecv (&msgsB[i], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[i]);
MPI_Recv (chunk, n, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[i]);

//do whatever I need on chunk[j] variables
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. Your code still has multiple issues. I would recommend that you replace all non-blocking calls (e,g, `MPI_Irecv`) by blocking ones (e.g. `MPI_Recv`).